# Не получаю значения по селектору

Tags: jquery

Есть HTML

```
<table class="reg_table" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="300px">Городской телефон:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="<?echo $users['phone']?>" class="reg_input"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="300px">Мобильный телефон:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?echo $users['mobile']?>" class="reg_input"/></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить" class="my_btn_blue save" style="font-size:14px; padding:5px 15px 5px 15px"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Хочу получить значение input но оно возвращает пустое, почему?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( ".save" ).click(function() { 
            //var id_users = <?echo $users['id']?>;
            var phone = $("input[name='phone']").val();
            var mobile = $("input[name='mobile']").val();
            //var email = "<?echo $email?>";
            alert($("input[name='phone']").val());
            $.ajax({
              url:'/ajax/update_user_info_phone',
              type : 'post',
              data:{'phone':phone,'mobile':mobile, 'email':email},
              success:function(r){
                $('#update_user').reveal({

            })         
              }
            });
        });      
});
</script>
```

Comment: В том примере кода что вы предоставили - все работает так как надо. Алерт выводит значение инпута. Если это было именно в этом проблема. https://jsfiddle.net/opy80g90/